# How can I fix my GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

I have 2 tables as seen below:
[image]

Now the question is : 
How can I have a view which shows the details of the last Owner? in other words I need the details of person who has MAX(StartDate) in tbl_Owners table?
I want to find the latest owner of each apartment.
I tried different approaches but I couldn't find the way to do that. 
I know I need to get the personID in a Group By clause which groups records by AppID but I can't do that

Thank you

Comment: `select MAX(StartDate) ....................... GROUP BY Orners.PersonID`

Comment: What is your Sql server version? Please tag properly. If it  supports `row_number() over()` function then use it.

Comment: @Serg it is 2014 Version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select t1.* from tbl_persons as t1 inner join 
(

    select t1.* from tbl_owners as t1 inner join 
        (
        select appid,max(startdate) as startdate from tbl_owners group by appid
        ) as t2
        on t1.appid=t2.appid and t1.startdate=t2.startdate
) as t2
on t1.personid=t2.personid
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your query:

```
JOIN (select AppId, MAX(StartDate) as MAxStartDate
      from dbo.tbl_Owners
      group by PersonId) o2
   ON dbo.tbl_Owners.AppId= o2.AppId and
      dbo.tbl_Owners.StartDate = o2.MAxStartDate
```

The sub-query above returns every AppId together with it's latest StartDate. Self-joining with that result will give you what you want.

Comment: I need to find the latest owner of each apartment. So I think I should to group by appID

Answer (score 1):

You can USE CTE for this purpose

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT AppID,PersonID,StartDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AppID ORDER BY StartDate DESC) RN
    FROM TableNAme
    GROUP BY AppID,PersonID,StartDate
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dbo.tbl_Owners.*,dbo.tbl_Persons.PersonFullname FROM dbo.tbl_Owners
INNER JOIN
dbo.tbl_Persons ON dbo.tbl_Owners.PersonID=dbo.tbl_Persons.PersonID
GROUP BY dbo.tbl_Owners.StartDate HAVING MAX(StartDate);
```

Use GROUP BY on StartDate instead on PersonID.

Answer (score 1):

Using row_number

```
select t.*, p.* -- change as needed
from (select *, rn= row_number() over(partition by AppID order by StartDate desc)
      from dbo.tbl_Owners
   ) t
join dbo.tbl_Persons p on t.rn=1 and t.PersonId = p.PersonId
```

using cross apply

```
select t.*, p.* -- change as needed
from dbo.tbl_Persons p 
cross apply (
   select top(1) * 
   from dbo.tbl_Owners o
   where o.PersonId = p.PersonId
   order by o.StartDate desc
   ) t
```